# processing multiple xml files and saving all the output inside a single .txt file

Tags: python, json, glob, os.path

i implemented through python,to parse a single XML file and process it and and the input and output (is in multiple lines) like this:

```
address = glob.glob('*.xml')
#print(address)
for single_add in address:
    xmlfile = single_add  
    items = parseXML(xmlfile)
    # species here is a list like this:
    # ['Neutrophil', 'Neutrophil', 'Microcyte', 'Giant platelet',   #'Microcyte', 'Platelet', 'Microcyte', 'Large platelet', 'Platelet', #'Platelet', 'Microcyte', 'Platelet', 'Large platelet', 'Microcyte', #'Platelet', 'Microcyte', 'Platelet', 'Microcyte', 'Platelet', #'Microcyte', 'Microcyte', 'Microcyte', 'Microcyte'] 
    print("Total no. of species provided are ")
    print(len(species))
    print(unique(species)) 
# unique just returns a list like this:
# [('Microcyte', 11), ('Large platelet', 2), ('Platelet', 7), #('Neutrophil', 2), ('Giant platelet', 1)]
```

now i have output of all the xml files in terminal, how to save this whole multiple lines output in single txt file,

Comment: Were those 3 print statements meant as target lines to be saved into a file?

Comment: you can run your script as following (if you're on Mac or Linux).
`python your_script.py > outputfile.txt`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes sir, actually these are output for files, like summary of that xml file, which i want to save for all other xml files n a single directory file

Answer (score 1):

replace the print statements with this:

```py
with open('filename.txt', 'a') as out_file:
    out_file.write("Total no. of species provided are\n{}\n{}\n".format(
        len(species),
        unique(species)))
```

[This article](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python) does a very good write-up of file handling in python